# How can I send the WCF request in Binary encoded format?

Tags: wcf, soap, binary

Need help in sending a request which is for WCF service. The service has Custom Binding. The request is needed in Binary encoded format.

I am getting the below error 
Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/xml' was not the expected type 'application/soap+msbin1'.

```
public static void Test(string username, string password)
    {
            using (var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler()))
            {
                var request = new HttpRequestMessage()
                {
                    RequestUri = new Uri(connecturi),
                    Method = HttpMethod.Post
                };
                var soapRequest = new AuthenticateUserRequest
                {
                    Username = username,
                    PasswordHash = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password))
                };

                request.Content = new StringContent(SoapRequestToString(soapRequest), Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));
                request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/xml");
                request.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "http://tempuri.org/IDataService/AuthenticateUser");

                HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
            }
    }
```

Comment: Side note, you are [using HttpClient wrong](https://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi234awuInaAhWKa1AKHdjqD_cQFggpMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Faspnetmonsters.com%2F2016%2F08%2F2016-08-27-httpclientwrong%2F&usg=AOvVaw0a0Pklclg_wNrIMVuxMVZE).

Comment: @MickyD - msbin1 is very much WCF.

Comment: @HenkHolterman and I could probably do a similar thing for TCP; MSMQ; or pipes.   Emulating what WCF does under the hood without using WCF doesn’t make it WCF

Comment: But very much _about_ WCF. Stop removing the most relevant tag.